# Convergence in $L_1$ and uniformly bounded in $L^2$ implies convergence in $L^p$, $1<p<2$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I am studying a qual and I do not know how to do the following question.

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to $f$ in $L^1$. Suppose in addition that $f_n\in L^2$ and there exists a constant $M$ such that $\|f_n\|_2<M$ for all $n$. I have already known $f\in L^2$. But I would like to prove that $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$, where $1<p<2$.

I have tried using Holder's inequality but without success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Hölder says
$$
\begin{align}
\int_A|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_A|f(x)|^{2-p}|f(x)|^{2(p-1)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\left(\int_A|f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{2-p}
\left(\int_A|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{p-1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
\|f\|_p^p\le\|f\|_1^{2-p}\|f\|_2^{2(p-1)}\tag{2}
$$

Comment: So we have $f\in L^p$, but why $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int |f_n-f|^p=0$?

Comment: Put $f_n-f$ in $(2)$ since you know that $\|f_n-f\|_1\to0$.